# TCL script unable to work with multiple camera on windows 7 platform

Tags: split, ffmpeg, windows-7, tcl, multiple-choice

My TCL script works properly for single camera. the TCL script is as follow :

```
proc liveStreaming {} {

    #open the config file.
    set f [open "C:/main/video_config.txt" r] 

    #To retrive the values from the config file.
    while {![eof $f]} {
        set part [split [gets $f] "="]
        set props([string trimright [lindex $part 0]]) [string trimleft [lindex $part 1]]
    }
    close $f 

    #camera selection to live streaming.
    set camera "video"
    append cctv $camera "=" $props(cctv)

    #ffmpeg command to capture live streaming in background
    exec ffmpeg -f dshow -s 1280x720 -i $cctv c:/test/sample.avi >& c:/test/temp.txt &

}
liveStreaming

//above code is to capture video using ffmpeg and tcl.
```

My text file "video_config" is as follow:

```
cctv=Logitech HD Webcam C525
```

as, i want it to run with multiple camera : the text file should be as follow  :

```
cctv=Integrated Webcam,Logitech HD Webcam C525
```

The problem is "," (comma), my TCL script is unable to predict the coma (,) . can any one provide me the proper TCL script which can predict the coma, so that my TCL script can work with multiple camera.

Error Report :

```html
ffmpeg version N-89127-g8f4702a93f Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libmfx
  libavutil      56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
  libavcodec     58.  3.103 / 58.  3.103
  libavformat    58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavdevice    58.  0.100 / 58.  0.100
  libavfilter     7.  2.100 /  7.  2.100
  libswscale      5.  0.101 /  5.  0.101
  libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
  libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
[dshow @ 05944ac0] Could not find video device with name [Integrated Webcam,Logitech HD Webcam C525] among source devices of type video.
video=Integrated Webcam,Logitech HD Webcam C525: I/O error
```

Comment: What is the actual problem? I mean, what is the error message, if any? I fail to parse that "my TCL script is unable to predict the coma (,)"

Comment: @kostix i have uploaded the error roport. the actually problem is the code return in while loop using TCL script is unable to predict the (,) coma passed in text file.

Comment: So, `ffmpeg` is telling you it can't find a webcam named "Integrated Webcam,Logitech HD Webcam C525", verbatim, in the system. Obviosly, it does not accept lists of devices. To me, it appears you have to get the list of devices and spawn several copies of `ffmpeg` — each reading from a *single* device.

Comment: @kostix can u help me with the code  as answer.  As the while loop in code is able to predict &quot;=&quot; . In the same way can the nested split and get can work together for getting multiple values after (=) equalto seperated by (,) coma.

Comment: Sorry but no, StackOverflow is about solving reasonably non-trivial problems, solutions to which might require special knowledge which might be hard to attain. The question of how to split a string on the `,` character is not one of them. Just complete a nearby tutorial and experiment in a sample script which *does not* call `ffmpeg` but rather just prints the results.

Comment: @kostix , but having tcl script to split a string using (,) coma, is hard for me. so plzz help me out.

Comment: Are you kidding? Your script already splits a string on the '=' character. Well, please don't take this my remark as being harsh but you're asking a questions about programming on a resource dedicated to programming, and it looks like you actually do not *want to learn* programming. That's plain weird. I surely can understand not every person wants to learn how to program but then they usually do not try to, well, program. Say, I'm dispassionate about accounting, but I'm not trying to do any accounting! ;-)

Comment: So if you're indeed serious about programming, I'd say you have to first work on adjusting your mindset about approaching this craft. Reading through [this classic essay](https://whathaveyoutried.com) might get you started or at least might nudge you to start reevaluating your approach to problem solving. As to your particular problem at hand, start by at least completing [the tutorial](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html) then move on to [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=string+split+site%3Awiki.tcl.tk) and then *experiment!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieved this with another `split`, using a `foreach` loop:

```
proc liveStreaming {} {

    #open the config file.
    set f [open "C:/main/video_config.txt" r] 

    #To retrive the values from the config file.
    while {![eof $f]} {
        set part [split [gets $f] "="]
        set props([string trimright [lindex $part 0]]) [string trimleft [lindex $part 1]]
    }
    close $f 

    #camera selection to live streaming.

    # let cams be the list of available cameras
    set cams [split $props(cctv) "," ]
    set idx 0

    # for each camera in cameras list    
    foreach cam cams {
        set cctv "video=$cam"

        #ffmpeg command to capture live streaming in background
        exec ffmpeg -f dshow -s 1280x720 -i $cctv "c:/test/sample-$idx.avi" >& "c:/test/temp-$idx.txt" &    

        # create a new index (to prevent two cameras to create the same file)
        incr idx
    }
}
liveStreaming
```